# Getting error when try to pass data from a php file back to JSON javascript

Tags: php, json

**Let's me describe what I'm working on before I ask my question:**

I'm building a clinic queuing management system, in part of the system, I have three files here, they are index.php, test.php and test.js respectively.

==> test.js will send request to test.php to get 2 JSON data, there are $queueNumber and $room stored in test.php. After that will append a new  in index.php and under that  will append 2  which shows $queueNumber and $room.

==> test.php produce a ticket number and a room number stored in $queueNumber and $room respectively.

==> index.php is just a file  that contain 2 table, 1 table for header and 1 table to show the ticket number and room number.

**The following is code of index.php**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>And San King EMR</title>
 </head>

<body>

<table width="95%" align="center" border="1">
 <tr>
  <th width="50%" style="font-size:40px;">Number</th>
  <th width="50%" style="font-size:40px;">Office</th>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="95%" align="center" border="1" id="queueDisplay">
</table>

<script src="/system/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**the following is the code of test.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    data:"";
    dataType: "json",
    success : function (data) {
        x=data.queueNumber;
        y=data.room;
        alert('The queue number is '+ x +' and the room is '+ y);
    },
});
});
```

**the following is code of test.php**

```html
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM queue WHERE status='calling' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $queueNumber = $row['queueNumber'];
    $room = $row['room'];
    $json = array("$queueNumber","$room");
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

**Question: When I try to run index.php, I get the following error message, I should I solve this error message?**

> error syntax error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column
>   1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

The file process.php should only include php code and data that should return. omit other html tags. So process.php would be only this:

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM queue WHERE status='calling' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $queueNumber = $row['queueNumber'];
    $room = $row['room'];
    $run = mysql_query("UPDATE queue SET status='called' WHERE ID='$ID'");
    $json = array("$queueNumber","$room");
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: if I'm not going to send data from display.php to process.php, can I delete the line (data:"";) in that process.js?

Comment: from that process.php, I can get the result like this if I run that page directly in browser  ==> ["A001","1"]
But, I cannot get any response from that display.html, I didn't get any javascript alert like I programmed in that process.js, where do you think could possibly goes wrong?

Comment: In ajax block, after data="" there should be comma not semicolon also in line 10 of js , there should not be comma after closing }

Comment: Also make sure that connect.php is empty from html tags and extra data